# Blurry PDF icons in Xcode

Tags: xcode, user-interface, pdf, interface-builder, asset-catalog

I'm trying to create image buttons in my macOS application. I've created an icon in a design program and exported it as a PDF, which I've added to the asset catalog in my project. However, when I use it as the image on an `NSButton`, it appears blurry. Here's an example of what I mean:

[image]

On the top left is how my icon (a simple square) renders on an `NSButton`. Top right is the zoomed-in version: you can see the aliasing. The bottom row is a screenshot from one of the image buttons in Xcode itself: crisp lines and no aliasing.

Is there some setting or property I need to check in order for my icons to be rendered properly?

Answer (score -2):

Can you use UIButton? I think implementing that would be simpler.
You can create UIView and then add a UIButton within the UIView, and make them equal width/height. Then you can add the image to the UIView.

Also, make sure you have the image set to aspect fit.

Comment: This question is about macOS; UIKit is iOS